# Annotations work with HighStock but not with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, annotations

My HTML code begins with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <script src="file:///[%sPath_ext%]jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///[%sPath_hc%]highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///[%sPath_hc%]annotations.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///[%sPath_hc%]dark-unica.js"></script>
```

and it works perfectly.
Now I thought that Highstock was necessary to use the chartarea.addAnnotation() method, but when I read the doc, I realize that Annotation module can be used also with Highcharts.
As I don't use any other specific function from Highstock, I try to use Highcharts instead.

But when I change the reference 'highstock.js' into 'highcharts'.js, I get a jquery script error!
Why?

Comment: Hi @FrancoisG, Could you reproduce that case in jsfiddle? Here everything seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vrt4uy3h/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
Actually, I do use some Highstock features, such as 'scrollbar'.
I guess that's why it gives errors when I use Highcharts.
My mistake!